# Sitecore 10.1 showing subitems icon even when there are no children

Tags: sitecore-commerce, content-editor

I have just installed Sitecore 10.1 and Sitecore Commerce 10.1. An unexpected behavior of Content Tree is that every item has this "subitems indicator" icon beside it even when there are no subitems.

When publishing items, we have to click that icon to check if it has children.

[image]

Is this a bug or is there any setting to remove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the following setting in Sitecore.config:

```
<setting name="ContentEditor.CheckHasChildrenOnTreeNodes" value="true" />
```

If set to false, it improves the Content Editor performance, but you cannot know if an item has children unless you click on it.